# Error removing broken mongo server package

Tags: server, apt, package-management, mongodb

Thanks in Advance,
i want to remove a broken package mongodb-org-server.
During installation, i installed using

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

but when m removing it, it gets stuck on mongodb-org-server and says that

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
mongodb-org-server*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 26.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 218521 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb-org-server (3.0.15) ...
Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i have tried all these commands, but no useful results were noticed

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org-server
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-server
```

please help me out..!

Comment: You already solved your problem with `dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mongodb-org-server`...but have now created another. You must remove all those files manually now. That egg cannot be un-cracked.

Comment: Your original problem was pretty simple:  `Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.` You merely needed to restart/re-enable the service, or (16.04 and newer) explicitly disable the service using systemd.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this problem before and in the end I had to go into mongodb-org-server.prerm (in /var/lib/dpkg/info/) and commented out the lines where it tries to stop the mongod.service, before using apt-get to remove it.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Also worked for me, good tip by the way. I would never realize it myself

Comment: @ZigguratOfUr How did you find out that you had to go into mongodb-org-server.prerm file? Awesome tip! Thanks!! :-)